# Is an adaptation against impact of fall a factor in babies' bones' structure?

Tags: human-biology, muscles, development, bone-biology, children

Obviously, babies' bones need to be flexible to get through the pelvic bone. But is that the only reason? Could it be that as babies aren't able to maintain stability, they need bones less prone to damage?